# tr bash command in terminal works but not when called from python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

When I run the command `cat file1 | sed 's/v //' | tr -d \\n > file2` manually from my terminal, it correctly removes all the v's from the file, and then all the linebreaks.

However, when I run `subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', '-ic', "cat file1 | sed 's/v //' | tr -d \\n > file2"])` from python, it **only removes the v's but not the linebreaks**. How is this possible and how do I fix it?

Comment: If you want to use pipes and redirections, they are features provided by your shell... so you'll need to ensure a shell is used in your `subprocess()` call. Your `cat` is also unnecessary as `sed` is perfectly able to read files itself.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, if I add `shell=True` to subprocess.run it no longer works at all, the python script just freezes indefinitely...

Comment: You need to escape the escapes, so use `\\\\n` instead of `\\n`. This is a typical example of escapes inflating exponentially with the number of parsing steps a string is going to go through.

Comment: ...or use a raw string: `r"cat file1 | sed 's/v //' | tr -d \\n > file2"`

Comment: Really, the _better_ solution would be to use one `subprocess.Popen` object for `sed`, a separate one for `tr`, and no shell at all... if you _really_ feel some bizarre need to use shell tools for something native Python can do perfectly well itself.

Comment: BTW, _in conjunction with_ the raw string approach from @InSync above, using single quotes would let you only use one backslash, as in `tr -d '\n'`

Comment: `p1 = subprocess.Popen(['sed', 's/v //'], stdin=open('file1, 'r'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE); p2 = subprocess.Popen(['tr', '-d', r'\n'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=open('file2', 'w'))`, roughly -- there are some extra bits I'm leaving out, but the subprocess docs (and other Q&A entries here) cover them.

Comment: Perhaps the pipeline is just an example but it's not too difficult to do natively in Python: `with open("file1") as f1, open("file2", "w") as f2: f2.write("".join(line.rstrip("\n").replace("v ", "", 1) for line in f1))` - you can use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) if you need to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command manually in the terminal, it is executed directly in the shell, and the shell manages the pipe (|) and output redirection (>) as well as the interpretation of escape sequences like \n. Therefore, this command works as expected. But when you run it using subprocess.run(), you are invoking a new shell process. This process interprets the command differently. To achieve the same result as running it manually in the terminal, use shell=True to run the command in a shell environment.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run("cat file1 | sed 's/v //' | tr -d '\\n' > file2", shell=True)
```

You can also use the below subprocess:
import subprocess

```
subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', '-ic', "cat file1 | sed 's/v //' | tr -d '\n' > file2"])
```

Alternatively you can use python's built-in string manipulation capabilities like below:

```
with open('file1', 'r') as infile, open('file2', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.replace('v ', '').strip())
```